# How to determine timing delay of SR-Latches?

Tags: logic-gates

[image]

I don't understand how to determine how long a delay should be. I understand 1.4 and 2.8 come from the delay of the gates, but how can you determine which delays first?

1. For example, why does Q' have a 1.4 ns delay while Q has a 2.8 ns delay. Why doesn't Q' have 2.8?
2. Don't they both go through the same two gates?
3. How do you determine Q' changes first?

Comment: Look at the feedback from the output of one gate into the input of another.  Depending on the arc, the delay will be either straight through the gate to the output (one gate delay), or it will first go through one gate and through the next to show up at the other output.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let's follow what happens when the SET input (1) is taken high:

- SET input (2) goes high.
- 1.4 ns later Q' (3) goes high.
- This turns off the input to the lower NOR gate at (4).
- 1.4 ns later Q (5) turns on.

For the SET operation Q' reacts with one gate delay. Q reacts with a further gate delay.

For the RESET operation Q reacts with one gate delay. Q' reacts with a further gate delay.

If you understand this you should be able to figure out the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Basically Q’ and Q are being updated every 1.4ns, however their value doesn’t necessarily change each 1.4ns (ex: at t0, Q=0 and then at 1.4ns Q gets updated to 0)

At t0: S = 1 and Q = 0.
This 1 and 0 goes into the top nor gate and after 1.4ns, Q’ = 0… hence Q’ is changed from its initial value 1, to 0 after 1.4ns (as seen on the timing diagram). 
* Note that while this was happening, (from t0 to 1.4ns), R was 0 and Q’ was initially 1. At t0, this 0 and 1 get fed into the bottom nor gate and produce 0… but Q was already 0 so its value doesn’t change (as seen on the timing diagram).

At t = 1.4ns: we now have Q’ = 0 and R = 0.
This gets put into the bottom gate, and after another 1.4ns, Q will become 1. (Hence after 2.8ns Q finally changes).
… And while this was happening, S = 1 and the initial Q = 0 went into the top nor gate and produced Q’ = 0… but Q’ was already 0 so it doesn’t change.

And so on and so on. If you keep going around the latch like that it will hopefully make sense.

Comment: Your opening statement, "*Basically Q’ and Q are being updated every 1.4ns ...*" reads as though there is some sort of periodic scan going on. This is probably not what you intended. How about "*Basically Q’ and Q are being updated **after** 1.4ns ...*" with some further tidy-up in the following text? Welcome to EE.SE.